# google.maps.Overlay is not a constructor

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hi I m trying to migrate a google maps V2 to google maps V3 project.

Here I m creating a prototype as below.It is in a seperate .js file other than the .js file containing function to initialize the map.

```
Ubicacion.prototype = new google.maps.Overlay();

Ubicacion.prototype.initialize = function(map) {
    var alias_ = this.alias_;
    var direccion_ = this.direccion_;
    var fecha_ = this.fecha_;
    var point_ = this.point_;
    var tipo_ = this.tipo_;
    var imagen_ = this.imagen_;
...
}
```

But I m getting "google.maps.Overlay is not a constructor". I understand by googling that it may be caused because initialization is happening before google maps is being loaded; and can be rectified by using google.setOnLoadCallback() for initizialising  objects.But I m not very clear in using the same.

Can any one please guide me?This is very urgent.

Comment: Is there a typo? Does the message really say "google.map.Overlay is not a constructor"; that would be true (it should be google.maps.Overlay...)

Comment: yea. It was a typo.It is saying google.maps.Overlay is not a constructor.Can you please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Put this code in a function, and call that function along with the rest of your maps initialization from the onload callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no such constructor.

I guess  what you try to use should be [`google.maps.OverlayView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#OverlayView)